# Generate Github self-hosted runner token automatically

Tags: github, github-api

I'm attempting to create a Terraform-integrated script that will create and configure a Google Cloud VM that will install Github Runner as self-hosted. The repository is under my workplace's 'organization' and it is closed to the public. Everything goes smoothly until I need to configure the runner. In repository instructions for creating self-hosted runner written as this:

```
# Create the runner and start the configuration experience
$ ./config.cmd --url https://github.com/my_work_place_organizaiton_name/repository_name --token ASZER2QS4UVEAL3YLMZ3DIMUIC
```

The issue is that, because it is an unattended script, it will run entirely on its own with no strings attached, and everything should be generated as automatically as possible. So I need a way to generate/retrieve this token `ASZER2QS4UVEAL3YLMZ3DIMUIC` automatically.

I think I found a way (correct me if I wrong) here: [Create a registration token for an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners#create-a-registration-token-for-an-organization). So far so good. I managed to create a powershell script to execute all steps in new Github self-hosted runner until the step where I need to generate token. Once I run the command (even in Github CLI) I get an error back like this:

```
gh api --method POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /orgs/my_work_place_organizaiton_name/actions/runners/registration-token
{
  "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-registration-token-for-an-organization"
}
gh: Must have admin rights to Repository. (HTTP 403)
gh: This API operation needs the "admin:org" scope. To request it, run:  gh auth refresh -h github.com -s admin:org
```

**I am an admin** in this repository but **not in the organization**, and I am afraid that no one will grant me admin access to the organization, and even more, I cannot simply put `admin:org` credentials in some script - this is a "no go."

So, my question is, how can I fully automate the generation of this Github token (which is generated for everyone in the instructions page without any admin privileges)?

Comment: You can also request a registration token limited to a specific repository by changing the scope https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners#create-a-registration-token-for-a-repository

Comment: @javierlga - sorry - I don't understand... Can not find any 'scope' in a link that you send. Could you elaborate a little bit ?

Comment: The endpoint is different, as you can see a token limited to a repository is `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runners/registration-token`  , that's different than the one for organizations `/orgs/{org}/actions/runners/registration-token`, so you can use the repo one as that's the one where you're an admin.

Comment: @javierlga Sadly - it does not work... :cry:  I could generate token by using `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runners/registration-token` url **only for my own** repositories. In my case I need to generate token for repository that exist in my Organization.... :( When using above link for organization repo I receive `404 Not found` error  :cry:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and catches it seems I found an answer. What is work for me is **generating token for repository** and not *generating token for repository in organization*.

According to Github documentation: [Create a registration token for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners#create-a-registration-token-for-a-repository) this is a `POST` request you must send from Github CLI for example:

```
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runners/registration-token
```

and according to documentation:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OWNER | string | Required | The account owner of the repository. The name is not case sensitive. |
| REPO | string | Required | The name of the repository. The name is not case sensitive. |

So I put my **organization name** as an `OWNER` and **not my username** and voila ! it is worked !

so - instead sending request as:

`/repos/my_user_name/REPO/actions/runners/registration-token`

I send it as:

`/repos/my_organization_name/REPO/actions/runners/registration-token`

and immediately get a valid token back.